# Check a proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{b^k}$ always converges when $b > 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We are given the following sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a}{b^k}$$

Where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b>1$.

So the best way I thought to do this was to try and apply the Integral Test for convergence. So $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$, $f(n) = a_n$, if $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$, then the series is convergent.

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac{a}{b^x} dx = \int \frac{a}{b^t} - \int_1^t \frac{a}{b^1} $$

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac{a}{b^x} dx = \frac{ab^{-t}}{ln(b)} - \frac{ab^{-1}}{ln(b)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} ab^{-x}= 0$$

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac{a}{b^x} dx = \frac{0}{ln(b)} - \frac{ab^{-1}}{ln(b)}$$

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_1^t \frac{a}{b^x} dx = -\frac{ab^{-1}}{ln(b)}$$

$$-\frac{ab^{-1}}{ln(b)} < \infty$$

Edit: It would be worth mentioning that I know very little about the properties of infinite series. I am not an university student, I have no formal education in mathematics past precalculus, so this was just pieced together by what I could find.

Comment: A simple quotient test would have sufficed

Comment: I would better try to express the series as $a\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1/b)^k$ and then use the geometric series. What does the condition on $b$ imply?

Comment: It seems as if you are claiming that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac {dx}{b^x}<0$, no?  But this is clearly false.  You dropped a sign somewhere.

Comment: conditions $a$ and $b$ are just any natural numbers

Comment: I understand that, but then I should be able to take $a=1,b=2$, no?  Your formula for the integral gives $-\frac {ab^{-1}}{\ln(b)}=-\frac 1{2\ln (2)}=-\ln(4)<0$.  As I say, you lost a sign somewhere.  I can't follow your derivation (the first line makes no sense, for example) so I can't see where the sign went.

Comment: To be sure, as others have pointed out, this is a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  There is a simple closed formula for the partial sums, and for the entire sum when it converges (which, as you say, is when $b>1$).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I am parsing through my notes now to see where I messed up. I just cant find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u_n=\frac{a}{b^n}=ae^{-nln(b)}$$

we have $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n^2|u_n|=0$$

since $b>1$ and exponential is faster than polynomial near $+\infty$.

thus

for enough large $n$,

$$0\leq n^2 |u_n|\leq 1$$ and

$$0\leq |u_n|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

by comparison, the series $\sum a_n$ is absolutly convergent.

Answer (score 0):

See that $$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty {a\over b^k} = a\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left({1\over b}\right)^k$$ and $\left|{1 \over b}\right| \lt 1$.